# Reading Encrypted XML file from software with PHP

Tags: php, xml, encryption

I am using a design program called 2020 Design. I am able to complete designs and then export them to a XML file using an Envisioneer XML format. Now, I didn't think I would run into any issues but I noticed the XML file is exported as encrypted. So I just can't simply load the file and begin to parse it in php like I would.

I've looked around for decrypting functions but noticed they are all going off a file that was encrypted with a similar function and have a passphrase or keyphrase in order to unlock the decryption. Am I missing something here? I'm just wondering if there was a decrypt function out there that could work for me, any suggestions in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: In order to decrypt something, you have to know which algorithm was used to encrypt it. You will also need some kind of key which would have to have been supplied by the actor that encrypted the file.

Comment: Maybe you have a program designated for the export, which is encrypting it. Try "Simple", to have it just save normally?

Comment: Well, that's the thing it's a design program that we purchased a while back. I will need to reach out to them then. So without a down there needs to be some sort of key supplied by them?